# Setting a class variable does not update instances of the original class

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, class-variables

I have a class:

```
class MusicCache(BaseDatabaseClass):
    dont_skip_duplicates = False
```

with an instance method

```
def is_skip_set(self):
    if MusicCache.dont_skip_duplicates is False:
        # skip duplicates
    else:
        # don't skip duplicates
```

There are 5 instances of this class running.

I then set the class variable from another class that has imported `MusicCache`:

```
class MQTTHandler(object):
    def set_skip_duplicates(self):
        MusicCache.dont_skip_duplicates = True
```

`is_skip_set()` always equates to false, even after calling `set_skip_duplicates()`.

I have tried making `dont_skip_duplicates` an instance variable, and passing all instances of MusicCache to MQTTHandler, and setting each instance's instance variable with `self.cache_instance_x.dont_skip_duplicates = True`, but this doesn't work either, I assume because when I pass the instances to `MQTTHandler` I create a local instance with the `self` assignment.

I have played with Java-style setters in the MusicCache class, and making the `dont_skip_duplicates` variable a `@property` to achieve the same thing, but nothing seems to be working.

What is the best way of setting this variable in all instances of the `MusicCache` class?

Comment: Just a heads up, don't use backticks for multiline code snippets.

Comment: Also, show a [mcve] of the problem.

Comment: protip: don't use `is` to compare booleans. Either use `==` or just `if some_boolean: whatever()`. `is` works due to 2 implementation details: `bool` subclasses `int` and small integers are cached. It is enough for one of these to change for all programs using `is` to compare booleans to break

Comment: I tried something similar and it works, what is the code where you instantiate those classes and perform the methods? Maybe something is wrong there?

Comment: [Your given code does not seem to be broken](https://repl.it/repls/ThinDevotedAutosketch). Something else is going on that you haven't told us about...

Comment: Could an underlying cause be the BaseDatabaseClass that the MusicCache class is inheriting? I am not a Python engineer and am just attempting to patch this massive legacy project.

Answer (score 0):

After poking around for a while we realised that the main loop is running a multiprocessing queue, which I assume was preventing variable updates across classes/instances.

Added a variable of type multiprocessing.Event to the main State class and can now set and get the variable state correctly.